# JTable larger than JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable

**EDIT: Sorry for many edits. I forgot what I wrote by myself.**

I use JPanel that has BoxLayout as root Panel for JFrame. I'm adding to this root Panel two other Panels: buttonPanel with FlowLayou and tabbedPane. Each tabbed Pane is created dynamically by pressing second button at the top. In tabbedPane there is a templatePanel with BoxLayout that contains three other general JPanels: Checkboxes Panel with FlowLayout, tablePanel with BorderLayout and another one with BoxLayout.

I'm adding a JTable to tablePanel with `BoderLayout.CENTER` and after running program JTable is way too big vertically and I need to resize frame. I need to add rows dynamically so I create an empty JTable with my custom `DefaultTableModel` (I overloaded `isCellEditable` method, nothing more) and then by checking checkboxes I fill it with data. 
JTable is also way too big than maximum rows number it is designed to hold.
What I mean:
[image]
How can I shrink it?

I create templatePanel with class's constructor (extends JPanel) by just `add.(templatePanel)`

code:

```
public TemplatePanel()
{
    model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[][] {}, new String[]
            {"<html>...</html>", "<html>...</html>",
                    "...", "...", "<html>...</html>",
                    "<html>...</html>", "...", "...",
                    "<html>...</html>"})
    {
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
        {
            return column == 1 || column == 3;
        }
    };

    templatePanel = new JPanel();
    tablePanel = new JPanel();

    templatePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(templatePanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    tablePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    checkBoxPanel = new JPanel();

    checkBoxPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    1 = new JCheckBox("...");
    2 = new JCheckBox("...");
    3 = new JCheckBox("...");
    4 = new JCheckBox("...");
    5 = new JCheckBox("...");
    6 = new JCheckBox("...");

    checkBoxPanel.add(1);
    checkBoxPanel.add(2);
    checkBoxPanel.add(3);
    checkBoxPanel.add(4);
    checkBoxPanel.add(5);
    checkBoxPanel.add(6);

    1.addItemListener(this);
    2.addItemListener(this);
    3.addItemListener(this);
    4.addItemListener(this);
    5.addItemListener(this);
    6.addItemListener(this);

    table = new JTable(model);
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

    table.setTableHeader(new JTableHeader(table.getColumnModel())
    {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            Dimension d = super.getPreferredSize();
            d.height = 50;
            return d;
        }
    });

    TableColumn firstColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    TableColumn secondColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
    TableColumn thirdColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
    TableColumn ninthColumn = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(8);

    firstColumn.setPreferredWidth(170);
    secondColumn.setPreferredWidth(50);
    thirdColumn.setPreferredWidth(30);
    ninthColumn.setPreferredWidth(100);
    table.setRowHeight(30);

    tablePanel.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    templatePanel.add(checkBoxPanel);
    templatePanel.add(tablePanel);
    add(templatePanel);
}
```

Comment: Some Java code and xml would be good to see.

Comment: Umm you are setting the row height to 30, can't you just make that value smaller? Also if you are going to need it to grow endlessly, put that thing in a JScrollPane

Comment: Unfortunately I can't make it smaller because frame is designed to be displayed on old CRT monitor with low resolution and I can't make frame that's 1300x1028. JTable needs to hold maximum 6 rows, not infinity. Whole content should be visible in that frame

Comment: Even if I comment out `table.setRowHeight(30);` it is still too big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the frame of the table to be smaller? Is that correct? If you're using BorderLayout, center will cover the entire frame unless you add something in the cardinal directions. Create a box and add it SOUTH to create a cushion between the bottom and the table. 
Again, If I'm not understanding this properly I apologize.

Edit:

Have you tried using setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500)) on the scrollpane?

Comment: The problem is I set the frame size to `setSize(new Dimension(800, 500));`. That's general dimension. Evertyhing in it should be smaller than that and still JTable is vertically bigger despite LayoutManager

Comment: @Colonder In the code you posted, I don't see you adding the table to the tablePanel

Comment: Have you tried using setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 500)) on the scrollpane?

Comment: Won't it collide with `LayoutManager` idea?

Comment: the LayoutManager just puts the panels in the appropriate location. So I wouldn't think that it could cause any problems since you're resizing the panel then giving it to layout manager to place.

Comment: It helped, post it as an anwser so that I could accept it

Comment: I added an edit so you can go ahead and accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

The basic logic should be:

```
JTable table = new JTable(model);
table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```

This will get rid of the extra vertical space.

Comment: This would do if I didn't create table empty but initiate it with some data. As I said I create empty table and then fill it with dynamic data

Comment: If there was some way to implement that logic in `itemStateChanged` listener to "reload" table each time checkbox is selected or deselected your solution would be best

Comment: @Colonder Why would it make any difference if the table had data or not?

Comment: @MadProgrammer when I apply camickr solution `table.getPreferredSize()` returns size that's preferred at the beginning when there's no data in the table. After I insert data the table won't resize automatically but will have size that was set initially

Comment: @Colonder Use a different value for the `preferredScrollableViewportSize` which better meets your needs, this effects the size of the `JScrollPane` itself and not the size of the table

Comment: @MadProgrammer of course `JScrollPane` and not `JTable` my bad but you execute that method on `table` object anyways. I was thinking about something like this in `itemStateChanged` listener each time checkbox is selected:
`table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize() + 30)` but this won't resize anything

Comment: You see I would need that resizing 'on the fly'